# Turning a table "on it's side" in asp.net - how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, mysql

How do I turn this table:

+------------+-----------------+
| Category + Subcategory  |
+------------+-----------------+
|Cat..........+ Persian.........|
|Cat..........+ Siamese........|
|Cat..........+ Tabby...........|
|Dog.........+ Poodle..........|
|Dog.........+ Boxer............|
+------------+----------------+

on it's side to get the following:

+------------+-----------------+
| Cat......... + Dog.............  |
+------------+-----------------+
+ Persian..+ Poodle.........+
+ Siamese + Boxer...........+
+ Burmese + ...................+
+------------+-----------------+

The initial table is from the following MySQL query:

```
select c.CATEGORYNAME, sc.NAME from subcategorydefinition sc
  join categorydefinition c on sc.CATEGORYID = c.CATEGORYID
  where c.ISDELETED = 0
  order by CATEGORYNAME, NAME ASC
```

And I want to display it in (probably) a Gridview.

Cheers!

Comment: I can't seem to think of how, but I believe that there is a SQL-only solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pivot is static in SQL. You need to know in advance the columns you want in output, so if the list of categories is not fixed, you can't use pivot directly.

If you were using Microsoft SQL Server (which I know you're not, but it's for the sake of example), you could use a dynamic query in a stored procedure, as described here:
http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx

Now, in MySql, there is no way to execute dynamic SQL on the sql side (no equivalent of EXECUTE or sp_executeqsl), so your best choice would be to generate a similar SQL query server-side (aspnet server-side).

Another simpler idea IMHO would be to forget about doing it in SQL, but to do the aggregation in your C# code.

Comment: +1 for forgetting SQL. Just use the query as-is and in the code-behind load the results into another container and bind the grid to that.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction on how to do the aggregration in C#?

Comment: @Ben: One simple way would be to new up a DataTable, then loop through your recordset.  Each time you find a new Category, add a column for it.  For each Subcategory, either add a new row or put it in an existing row with null in that column.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [pivot](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table)

Comment: That seems to be more about aggregates. Can I do the same for a "list" scenario like the one described above?

Comment: I don't think Pivot will work because the person wants the otherwise ROW label groupings as columns...

Answer (score 0):

To do this in SQL, you'd need to dynamically generate your query based on the available set of values in the "Category" column.  This is usually fairly painful and error prone, regardless of whether you do it in pure SQL (in a sproc) or in code (dynamic SQL).

I'd recommend reading your values from the database in the way that they are stored, then dynamically creating a DataTable or similar structure to use as the datasource for your UI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working version of MySql handy but this will work as long as there is always more cats than dogs because of the left join at the end of the script.  I forgot that there isn't a full outer join in MySql but you could use this [logic](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/) to try it out.

But the point of this is that if you have two tables with arbitrary keys you can join on the keys to get the results lined up like you want.

```
-- drop tables
 DROP TABLE dbo.cat
 DROP TABLE dbo.dog

 --create dog table
 create table dog (
 dog_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 ,dog varchar(50)
 )

 --add dogs only
 insert into dog (dog)
 select subcategory 
  FROM play.dbo.test 
 where category = 'Dog'

 --create cat table
 create table cat (
 cat_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 ,cat varchar(50)
 )

 --add cats only
 insert into cat (cat)
 select subcategory 
  FROM play.dbo.test 
 where category = 'cat'

 -- disply everything
 SELECT cat 
      , dog
  from dog d
 --full outer join cat c
 left join dog d
 on d.dog_id = c.cat_id
```